# Sliding login forum troubles

Tags: jquery, css

I was trying to figure out how people made stuff like this: [image]

Now I've looked up plenty of ways on how to do this and look at the scripts plenty of times, but I don't understand how they hide the login forum (or whatever slides over). Though I'm barely any good with jQuery or JS. I'm moderately good with CSS, but not to this extent (if this is possible with CSS3).

Could someone show me some way of doing this? I don't mean just plop a script down, I mean how I'd go about doing this. I've thought of ways, but the ways I'm thinking of seem way too complicated and I feel like I'm overthinking it. This is what I've been using as a reference or playing around with jQuery trying to do it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myJNXG

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="regLink">Register</a>
    <a href="#" class="regLink">Login</a>
  </div>
  <div id="log">
    Username
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    Password
    <input type="text" name="username">
  </div>
</div> 


#buttons {
  float: left;
}

#log {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THEORETICALLY this should work, but CSS directional transitions are messed up in the current generation of browsers.  You might want to mess with transparency instead of sliding to get something in pure CSS.

### What should be working

#### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kn2srwsL/

#### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="regLink">Register</a>
    <a href="#log" class="regLink">Login</a>
  </div>
  <div id="log">
    Username
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    Password
    <input type="text" name="username">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
}
#log {
    margin-left:300px;
    opacity:0;
    transition:margin-left 1s, opacity  .5s;
}
#log:target{
    margin-left:0;
    opacity:1;
}
```

#### Why it doesn't work

Browser support?  I really have no clue.  If anyone has any suggestions feel free to give them.

### Alternative

#### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/t08sjw25/

#### CSS (HTML is the same)

```
div{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
}
#log {
    opacity:0;
    z-index:-45;
    transition:opacity  .5s;
}
#log:target{
    z-index:45;
    opacity:1;
}
```

#### Why it works

Browser support?  Honestly it does what it's supposed to and works in the same way the slide does.

### Notes

Chrome supports the sliding transition up until about 90% of the width of the container.  Then things get weird.  If Chrome is your target browser, you can use the first example with `margin-left:90%` and transition opacity to keep things subtle.  IE and Firefox seem to act weird at any width.

Comment: Why did you set the z-index to -45/45? Why that far? Just taking notes.

Comment: @ErraticFox  No specific reason. One index should be lower than the other; the numbers are perfectly arbitrary. I really have no standard for z-indexes, so season to taste.

Answer (score 0):

I made a suggestion for you. Hope it helps.

javascript

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {

    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = { direction: 'right' };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = this.id;

    $('#log').toggle(effect, options, duration);
});
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  margin:0px auto;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.buttons {
  float:left;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  margin-top:200px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  border-top:1px solid #000;
}
.register {
  float:left;
  width:250px;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}
.login {
  float:left;
  width:250px;
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
}
#log {

  float:left;
  color:Green;
    background-color:#eee;
    border:2px solid #333;
    display:none;
    text-align:justify;
 z-index:2;
  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="register">Register</div>
    <div class="login">
    <button id="slow" class="myButton">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="log">
    Username
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    Password
    <input type="text" name="username">
     <button id="fast" class="myButton">Cancel</button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Working **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/xbGvMP)**

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, but how would I know how to add more variables? Like would I add var hide or?